# Pattern recognition, maximum likelihood, naive Bayes classifier

Tags: matlab, pattern-recognition

I am given 2 classes ("class1.dat" and "class2.dat") that consist of rows, and each row is a vector of 20 characteristics (20 values).

I take 10, arrange them with the fisher ratio and keep the best 5 results, then estimate the value of each normal distribution (assuming they are normally distributed) with maximum likelihood and the calculate the error with the naive Bayes classifier.

This is my code:

```
% i take 10 random characteristics

    C1= class_1(:,1:10)
    C2= class_2(:,1:10)                  
% FDR matrix initialize

    FDR=zeros(1,10);                   
%Calculate fisher ratio
%[t]=Fisher(x,y) where t:fisher ratio,x:data vector of first class,y: ...of second class

    for i=1:10
    FDR(i)=Fisher(C1(i,:),C2(i,:));                
    end 
%i find that the highest fisher ratio are 1,3,4,5,7 so i save them in a new matrix X

    X1=[C1(:,1),C1(:,3),C1(:,4),C1(:,5),C1(:,7)];
    X2=[C2(:,1),C2(:,3),C2(:,4),C2(:,5),C2(:,7)];
    X=[X1;X2];
%Calculate the Gaussian ml estimate
%[m,S]=Gaussian_ML_estimate(X) where X:LxN matrix m:L dimensional estimate of mean and %S:LxL dimensional estimate of convariance

    [C1mean_mle, C1cov_mle]=Gaussian_ML_estimate(C1');                   
    [C2mean_mle, C2cov_mle]=Gaussian_ML_estimate(C2');             
%I put together the estimates to use them in the last function, the naive bayes

    Cmean_mle(:,1)=C1mean_mle;
    Cmean_mle(:,2)=C2mean_mle;
    Ccov_mle(:,:,1)=C1cov_mle;
    Ccov_mle(:,:,2)=C2cov_mle;
```

I am troubled as to what I do next. I have a function:

```
[z] = bayes_classifier(m,S,P,X)
```

INPUT ARGUMENTS:
   m:      lxc matrix, whose j-th column is the mean of the j-th class.
   S:      lxlxc matrix, where S(:,:,j) corresponds to
           the covariance matrix of the normal distribution of the j-th
          class.
   P:      c-dimensional vector, whose j-th component is the a priori
           probability of the j-th class.
   X:      lxN matrix, whose columns are the data vectors to be
           classified.

OUTPUT ARGUMENTS:
z:      N-dimensional vector, whose i-th element is the label
           of the class where the i-th data vector is classified.

and this function:

```
[clas_error] = compute_error(y,t_est)
```

computes the error of a classifier based on a data set.

INPUT ARGUMENTS:
 y:      N-dimensional vector containing the class labels of the N
           vectors of a data set.
t_est:  N-dimensional vector containing the labels of the classes to
           which each one of the vectors of X has been assigned according
           to a classification rule.
OUTPUT
clas_error: the classification error.

I know it was a long post so thanks for reading those who read :)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, like you said, this long post contains way too much info. Please reduce the question and keep only the relevant parts to your question, because quite frankly... I never found a question, I got lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with naive Bayes, and from what you're writing I get the sense I could probably answer your question. I'm just not completely sure what it is. Could you elaborate?

The one thing I'll note is that I think is a bit unusual is that you are talking about covariances. The entire assumption of naive bayes is that the characteristics are conditionally independent given the class. If you are using covariances, then each state really has data drawn from an n-dimensional gaussian (as opposed to n, independent, 1 dimensional gaussians). At that point, it's not really naive Bayes, but a Gaussian Mixture Model. Also a very good model. It's just way way more expressive, and therefore more suitable when you have a much larger quantity of data (it's highly prone to overfitting smaller data sets).

Also, using the Fischer information criterion to eliminate less relevant data is kind of interesting. Aside from alleviating computational burden for later, I'm not sure I see the advantage. When you go ahead and fit naive Bayes, it is possible to extract later which elements are more significant in deciding the label.